# Azure DSC - A system shutdown is in progress

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-powershell, dsc

I've got a couple of azure templates that deploy VMs with a DSC extension. This morning, I've started getting the following intermittent errors in deployments:

> "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension
>   'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension failed
>   to install: A system shutdown is in progress. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007045B).\r\nMore information about the failure can be found in the
>   logs located under
>   'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.17.0.0'
>   on the VM.\r\nTo retry install, please remove the extension from the
>   VM first. \"."

I can't find any information about this error in this context. Inside my template, my DSC extension depends upon my VM

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
],
```

So I assume it's smart enough not to try installing before the VM is finished provisioning but I don't believe I've changed anything to make this happen. Is this an intermittent error with azure VM deployment or have I broken my template?

Comment: I’ve had the same happen to me, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Boomerang Sorry, no solution from me but, in my case, the problem did resolve on its own after a while.